# When should I use AssetDataBase.SaveAssets() in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, editor

I just realized that I do not really understand what is the point of method `AssetDataBase.SaveAssets()`.

For example, I use `SetDirty()` method for non-scene objects (prefabs, scriptable objects), when I changed some of those.

So, my question is what is the purpose of `AssetDataBase.SaveAssets()` method ?
Should I call it after creating directory or what ?

Looks like it interchangeable methods, but I think it is not.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`SetDirty()` and `SaveAssets()` are related, but perform different functions.

At a minimum you need to call `SetDirty()` to indicate that the specified Unity Object file (such as a prefab or ScriptableObject, but not objects that are part of the current scene) has changed and needs to be saved. Note that directories are *not* Unity Objects.

The next time the project is saved, any assets that are `SetDirty()` will be saved.

If you don't want to wait, you can call `AssetDataBase.SaveAssets()` to save marked assets immediately. It acts as a sort of "flush" operation.

- [EditorUtility.SetDirty(UnityEngine.Object target)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.SetDirty.html)
- [AssetDatabase.SaveAssets()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.SaveAssets.html)

Answer (score 0):

From the Unity docs :

> Description
>
> Writes all unsaved asset changes to disk.
>
> This function does the same thing as EditorApplication.SaveAssets,
>   with the exception that it is not permitted to be called during
>   serialization.

So you use it when you want to write all the unsaved asset changes to disk. For example you have some script that goes around and changes the settings of a bunch a textures. At the end of that operation you call that method and the changes will be saved.

Comment: Afaik, it is recomended to use SetDirty() method after change some non-scen object. And it works. So, why should I use SaveAssets ? Looks like it interchangeable methods, but I think it is not.

Comment: @VladislavHromyh I believe the difference is whether the user saves the changes manually (`SetDirty`), or your script does it automatically (`SaveAssets`). In some cases you might want a manual review of changes, and in other cases you might not.

Comment: @UriPopov Can you just give an example for difference between approaches or cases that you meant. Changes manually and does it automatically. Cause in two ways, I change data. From script. Or not ?